# Sort all FB comment count for last 24 hours

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new to FB development, all help appreciated.

I've added FB comment box to all articles of my website.  Now I want to get a list of most commented articles(urls) recently. Like a top 10 list of articles most discussed for the past 24 hours in my website....

What approach should I use? Can this be achieved using FQL?

Comment: @downvoter - If we already have a facebook-api tag with over 7000 questions, you'll have a hard time arguing that this question be is too localized.

Answer (score 0):

This question talks about doing batch requests for comments (comment counts would be similar) for many URLS on the same site: [Facebook fb:comments Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736210/facebook-fbcomments-graph-api)

The comment section on the FQL documentation seems to address batch retrieval too. You can then sort out the most popular ones and display links: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

Good luck.